# Website image upload choose special folder

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, progressive-web-apps, dropzone.js

is it possible to select a special folder on mobile devices for an website image upload with html5 and js? Is there any way? Script, plugin, solutions...?

Like whatsapp. By default the gallery view is shown. 
I tried a bit with dropzone.js. Works fine but differently behaves on different smartphones. Always other folder, problems with multiselect, sometimes...

I often hear that PWAs are the future. Is maybe this a way? Otherwise this is still a big point compared to native app.
I'm happy about your help.

Thanks Moni

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

for images accept="images/*" or specify image format(accept="images/png"),

for example this

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" required="" name="image">
```

by default the gallery view would be opened if visited on android since all that is required is an image(s)